# Overriding Rails mislav-will_paginate plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, overriding, will-paginate

I'm working with the Rails mislav-will_paginate plugin to paginate my records. I want to produce the following output, regardless of whether there were multiple pages:

```
X - Y of Z
1 - 100 of 1826
```

will_paginate in WillPaginate::ViewHelpers returns nil if there was only one page of records. I want to override this in the cleanest possible way to produce the above output if there was only one page, or the above output surrounded by the usual output if there were multiple pages.

I've overridden WillPaginate::LinkRenderer's to_html method to produce this output, but I can't figure out how to produce it if there is only one page of records.

Should I be moving the code to produce X - Y of Z somewhere else and calling it both from my overridding to_html method, and from the place where I make my will_paginate call if it returns nil? If so, where should it live?

Comment: I'm assuming these numbers represent the number of items shown on the current page and how many there are total? And you want to always display this whether or not the pagination links exist? In that case, why not keep it outside of the will_paginate call entirely and implement it in your view or custom helper method?

Comment: Both assumptions are correct. I'm keen to roll them together because they're logically related; every time I call will_paginate I want to also display the totals. I also want to display the totals in between the page links that will_paginate produces, ala Gmail. The cleanest way to do this seems to be to get will_paginate to output the totals in its to_html method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did:

- Created a module Paginator
- Included the Paginator module in my model's helper
- Called Paginator.paginate in my views
- Defined Paginator.paginate to call Paginator.produce_totals if there was only one page, or to call will_paginate (the normal method) for multiple pages
- Defined Paginator.produce_totals to output the "X - Y of Z" totals as above
- Included the Paginator module in my WillPaginate::LinkRenderer overriding class
- Called Paginator.produce_totals at the appropriate point in my overriding to_html method

Phew! Can post code if it's useful to anyone - just ask.

Comment: Why not make this a plugin which extends will_paginate, or fork/branch will_paginate to include this support and submit a pull-request?